# Why won't Sublime Text3 run the code webbrowser.open('URL')

Tags: sublimetext3, python-webbrowser

When I run the code:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('https://youtube.com')
```

in sublime text 3, it gives me this:

```
/bin/sh: osascript: command not found
/bin/sh: osascript: command not found
/bin/sh: osascript: command not found
/bin/sh: osascript: command not found
```

and then it says code finished. However, when I run the same code in terminal it works perfectly fine. Is there some kind of package that I need to install?

Comment: What exactly are you doing to run the code?

Comment: It looks to me like you're trying to use AppleScript build system to execute Python code. With the little info you provide, it's hard to guess the reason for that behaviour. Is you code detected properly as Python (see the lower right of the Sublime Text window – a click let's you change it). Next, check the selected build system in the Tool menu. If "Automatic" is selected, you can force Sublime Text to use the Python build system.

Comment: well this is only part of the actual code, but I'm just trying to get it to open the URL, in my browser.

Comment: Also, yes, python is selected in the bottom right, and my build system is set up to be a specific one for python 3, however, when I change it to automatic, it stilll gives me the same error